# How to export/convert line projection to excel table and order the Y coornidate

Tags: image-processing, dm-script

I wrote a code that can get line projection (intensity profile) of an image, and I would like to convert/export this line projection (intensity profile) to excel table, and then order all the Y coordinate. For example, except the maximum and minimum values of all the Y coordinate, I would like to know largest 5 coordinate value and smallest coordinate value. 
Is there any code can reach this function? Thanks,

```
image line_projection
Realimage imgexmp
imgexmp := GetFrontImage()
number samples = 256, xscale, yscale, xsize, ysize
GetSize( imgexmp, xsize, ysize )
line_projection := CreateFloatImage( "line projection", Xsize, 1 )
line_projection = 0
line_projection[icol,0] += imgexmp
line_projection /= samples
ShowImage( line_projection )
```

Comment: Are you asking for code to export to Excel or to sort the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Finding a 'sorted' list of values

If you need to sort though large lists of values (i.e. large images) the following might not be very sufficient. However, if your aim is to get the "x highest" values with a relatively small number of X, then the following code is just fine:

```
number nFind = 10
image test := GetFrontImage().ImageClone()
Result( "\n\n" + nFind + " highest values:\n" )
number x,y,v
For( number i=0; i<nFind; i++ )
{
    v = max(test,x,y)
    Result( "\t" + v + " at " + x + "\n" )
    test[x,y] = - Infinity()
}
```

Working with a copy and subsequently "removing" the maximum value by changing that pixel value. The `max` command is fast - even for large images -, but the `for-loop` iteration and setting of individual pixels is slow. Hence this script is too slow for a complete 'sorting' of the data if it is big, but it can quickly get you the n 'highest' values.

Answer (score 0):

### This is a non-coding answer:

If you havea LinePlot display in DigitalMicrograph, you can simply *copy-paste* that into Excel to get the numbers.

> i.e. with the LinePlot image front most, preses CTRL + C to copy 
> (make sure there are no ROIs on it). 
> Switch to Excel and press CTRL + V. 
> Done.
> [image] ==> [image]